# How to scrape a website using following pagination in bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, pagination, beautifulsoup

I have a script that scrapes a specific website, where the number of a page is defined with `?start={}`. [This site](http://rl.odessa.ua/index.php/ru/poslednie-novosti?start=0).

This is my script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

def parse():
    for i in range(0, 480, 5):
        html = urlopen('http://rl.odessa.ua/index.php/ru/poslednie-novosti?start={}'.format(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

        for article in soup.findAll('article', class_ = 'item'):
            try:    
                print('\t' + article.find('h1').find('a').get_text())
                print(article.find('p').get_text() + '\n' + '*'*80)
            except AttributeError as e:
                print(e)

parse()
```

At the bottom of the page is located div.pagination with a.next. [Here's a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i21bW.jpg)

Is it a bad practise using `range()` instead of pagination? Anyway, please help me to rewrite the code above using pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whichever method works for you is fine, but locating the next button would make things easier. It could be done as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

def parse():
    base_url = 'http://rl.odessa.ua/index.php'
    url = 'http://rl.odessa.ua/index.php/ru/poslednie-novosti?start=0'

    while True:
        html = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

        for article in soup.findAll('article', class_ = 'item'):
            try:    
                print('\t' + article.find('h1').find('a').get_text())
                print(article.find('p').get_text() + '\n' + '*'*80)
            except AttributeError as e:
                print(e)

        next_button = soup.find('a', class_='next', href=True)

        if next_button:
            url = base_url + next_button['href']
        else:
            break

parse()
```